# Make BASH's Tab Completion Fill In First Match?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is there any way to make BASH fill in the first match when I press TAB, kind of like the Windows command prompt?

(It should still display the list of matches, but it should cycle through them when I keep on pressing tab.)

i.e. the goal here is to be able to fill in ***any*** match with **only** the TAB key, given enough presses -- like in Windows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the following to your `.inputrc` file, (exact location varies between systems):

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

This maps TAB to menu-complete, which auto-completes the first match.

Then add (or uncomment) `show-all-if-ambiguous`, this shows the list of possible completions on the first TAB press.

For example, in your (possibly) `.inputrc` file:

```
# On RHEL 8.3 - $HOME/.inputrc
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

Alternatively, you can set menu-complete per session (without editing `.inputrc`) by doing

```
bind '"\C-i" menu-complete'
```

Comment: No. That's definitely **nothing** like the Windows command prompt. :-)

Comment: +1 almost!!! It's what I want, but is there any way to make it do that *and* display the menu if it's ambiguous? (It might be asking for too much, I know, but I'm hoping it's possible.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: if it's what you want, accept it, this helps people get the right answers fast.  As for your new request to do both at once, I don't believe it's possible, but who knows?...  You can however bind `menu-complete` to another key-sequence, like `"\M-s"` for `Meta+S`, so you can chose at will.

Comment: Well, the original version of my question kind of said "*it should **still display the list of matches***", so what requested in the comment was nothing new -- it was already in the question. I just +1'd your answer because it got part of the question right. :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: sorry, I overlooked that part (5 AM...)

Comment: You know what? It seems like it's actually doing exactly what I want: First showing the menu, and then cycling through the options! I don't think I saw this on the first computer I tried (maybe I wasn't paying attention), but it seems to be working perfectly! :) (Edit: It seems like you need both this setting **and** `show-all-if-ambiguous` to be on for this to work.)

Comment: @Philomath Ah the beautiful power of the web + people. Your answer helped me this morning, nearly an _entire decade later_! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Though I don't know about getting this functionality to work with bash, zsh comes with set up with exactly what you want by default. Check out [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/).

zsh has most of the features of bash with some added functionality out of the box, like the ability to navigate with only tab and enter!

Most linux distributions come with a package for installing zsh.

Comment: ... oh my zsh!! That's interesting, I'll take a look at it... it may or may not do what I need.

Comment: Glad I could help. What distribution are you using? I can give you a more in depth answer with a guide on how to install zsh and oh my zsh.

Comment: +1 I installed zsh, it seems pretty awesome! If I don't run into any problems I might accept this too, thanks! :) (I'm using Ubuntu btw.)

Comment: Awesome, if you just ran apt-get install zsh and then ran the auto installer for oh-my-zsh [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), you should be good to go. Let me know if you need any help setting it up.